# Add synonym "windows-10-creators-update" -> "windows-10-v1703"

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

The various updates for Windows 10 should have tag synonyms for their official titles. This would include the following:

- [windows-10-creators-update](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-creators-update) -> [windows-10-v1703](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-v1703)
- [windows-10-anniversary-update](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-anniversary-update) -> [windows-10-v1607](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-v1607)
- [windows-10-november-update](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-november-update) -> [windows-10-v1511](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-v1511)

Interestingly, [windows-10-creator-update](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-creator-update) is already a synonym of [windows-10-v1703](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-v1703) despite being a typo of the actual update name. :P

Comment: I would but it's not possible. Tag names are limited to a maximum of 25 characters ...

Comment: `windows-10-creator-update` is exactly 25 characters :)

Comment: @DavidPostill That's a clever workaround. Would `windows-10-nov-update` work as a tag? Otherwise users would need to know the exact update number to use the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The various updates for Windows 10 should have tag synonyms for their official titles.

Agreed. Tag names are limited to a maximum of 25 characters, hence the 'misspelled' [windows-10-creator-update](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-creator-update)

Proposal:

Use [windows-10-nov-update](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-nov-update) and [windows-10-anniv-update](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-10-anniv-update) for the other 2 synonyms.

Comment: i will go with whatever the community decides, but honestly, this assumes that every feature update will also have a release name.  Worth pointing out that, not every major build of Windows 10, has a release name.  This leaves out the build which was released in July 2015.  It seems we are making the tags unnecessarly complicate.   Wouldn't it be easier to use Threshold 1, Threshold 2, Redstone 1, Redstone 2, Redstone 3?  Instead of the release names?

Comment: @Ramhound Fair point.

Comment: @Ramhound The main point of tag synonyms is to auto-correct scenarios where uses may try to use a different name for an already existing tag. If I've just updated to the Windows 10 Creators Update, I'd naturally try to tag my question `windows-10-creators-update`

Comment: That is my point, using the existing tag notation for the feature updates ( (i.e. v1703, v1607, v1511), is more forgiving then attempting to use a notation which places the release's name in the tag.  Because what  happens when `Windows 10 Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious` feature update is released?

Comment: @Ramhound Write an opposing answer and we can let the community vote :)

Answer (score 1):

> The various updates for Windows 10 should have tag synonyms for their
>   official titles.

This assumes that every feature update will also have a release name associated with it.  There are already exceptions to the "feature update" has a name rule.  The exception of course being the build released back in July 2015.  It is also true that in that case, it also does not have a version notation, i.e. v1703, v1607, v1511

I suggest, we make the tags synonyms of one another, only if, additional tags are created for that release.  I also suggest the primary tag notation should be that of the release date notation (i.e. v1703, v1607, v1511).

If and when, additional tags are created for a major feature release, we can link the synonym link at that point.

Comment: *If and when, additional tags are created for a major feature release*...IMO eliminating additional tags isn't the only reason to proactively create release-name synonyms. Having release-name synonyms already available enables more accurate tagging of questions, particularly in cases where users don't know or realize the significance of their build number.

Comment: @Twisty - The number of users who have asked a question (which I have seen), about Windows 10 who didn't know the build of the feature update they were running, can be counted on one hand.

Comment: If users felt the build number was the best way to communicate their version of Windows, I'd expect to see more question titles mentioning *build 1703* instead of *Creators Update*, the latter which appears much more prevalent.